# TypeORM relation

Tags: javascript, typescript, nestjs, typeorm

Can someone tell me why I can't use `relation` in my `createQuerybuilder`:

```
let user = await this.conn.getRepository(UserEntity)
                          .createQueryBuilder('user')
                          .relation('orders')
                          .orderBy('user.id', 'ASC') // 'Property 'orderBy' does not exist on type 'RelationQueryBuilder<UserEntuty>.
```

my error is throwing at `.orderBy`, but is not problem with orderBy because when i put in this place a diffrent function, this error is still exists

thanks for any help

Comment: As I can see in documentation relation takes two argument. [Relation Function](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/1c09dc31f3e4d64657bf711228741ae7b10f4088/src/query-builder/QueryBuilder.ts#L279)

Comment: @xMayank i see, but when i add my entity into this relation, i have still this same error

Comment: Let's use `leftJoin()` or `innerJoin()` instead of `relation()`. It will be smth like that 
`await this.conn.getRepository(UserEntity).createQueryBuilder('user').innerJoin('user.orders', 'order').orderBy('user.id', 'ASC')`

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what are you looking for:

```js
const users = await this.conn.getRepository(UserEntity)
                              .createQueryBuilder('user')
                              .leftJoinAndSelect('user.orders', 'orders')
                              .orderBy('user.id', 'ASC')
                              .getMany();
```

In the code above you will get a an array of users. Each user has an array of orders. This is good for you?

See the docs [here](https://typeorm.io/#/select-query-builder/inner-and-left-joins) about *joins* in TypeORM.

It's better using *joins* for a SELECT operation rather than the *relation* method. Relation docs [here](https://typeorm.io/#/relational-query-builder).

Hope it helps :)